# How can I make a copy of some branch with regenerated hash ids of changesets in Git?

Tags: git, branch, archive

I can make a copy of any branch via several ways, but let's take:

```
git branch copyBranch
```

It will make a new branch with the same state as the current one has.

If to use `git log` you can see, that hash ids of commits are the same.

I can regenerate in the copy branch the new ids using `git replace --edit` with the `git filter-branch`.

But I want to do this in more elegant way. Maybe there is a more simple git command for the such aim.

If you want to ask me `why do I want it?`

Because, I want to make copy of branches, associate them with certain tag, regenerate ids for each commit of the archive branch for passing the possible conflicts. Then only merge the original branch with another one and close (delete) it.

So, does exist more elegant way for this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the ids? why not adding new annotated tag and using it?

Comment: @codeWizard why do I need the same ids in the ARCHIVE branch? they will be independent, and there won't be possible conflicts with the existed commits... also what if I would like to restore it?

Comment: You said you change the commit ids

Comment: @codeWizard yes I did say it, because of: 1). possible restore 2). not making conflicts with the existed commits/merge connections

Comment: Git will not generate conflicts if the file content was not changed, regarding restore you can always use the original branch

Comment: @codeWizard I know that Git has an immutable model and even using the git replace --edit where you can redefine parents ids and etc, the git will regenerate some ids because of the already said the `immutable model`, conflicts may be different, for e.g. non-standard merge strategies or rebasing the branch or even just deleting some commit from branch like A-B-C -> A-C. As for me, I want to have a clean copy/archive of branch which will have the different ids for the future possible different ways of work.

Comment: Now i fully understand you, in got you can use revert to delete commits, cherry-pick to add commits to any other branch etc. but git track the content of the file, so each file will have the same SHA-1 if it has the same content so i don't see how you can generate different id for the same content.

Comment: @codeWizard As far as I know, revert doesn't delete commits. Have checked right now (http://pastebin.com/dNAxrtXu), maybe there are some special cases, but it's another story. About files... AFAK, they are presented as BLOB-objects with their own SHA1-hash (which later will be used for generating commit hash id) and one of the simplest way for making conflict with files is `git replace --edit <blobId>`, then change something in file and make  `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter . -f`. If to use `git ls-files stage` you may see, that its blob id didn't change, log: http://pastebin.com/GGEaDmPV

Comment: As far as I know, revert doesn't delete commits , its true, it doesnt its "reverting" the code to its prior content. All the above comment is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As for me, I want to have a clean copy/archive of branch which will have the different ids for the future possible different ways of work.

You don't have to do anything else for creating an "archive" branch than git branch `copyBranch`.

Your "`currentBranch`" (which you just "copied") will evolve independently: maybe there will be rebase which will change its SHA1, but that will have no effect on your copy branch.

Suppose you delete a commit (through a rebase --interactive) in your current branch, here is the result:

```
A--B--C (currentBranch, copyBranch)
```

To (after `git rebase -i`):

```
A--B--C (copyBranch)
 \
  C' (currentBranch)
```

See? Your current branch will have different SHA1! (for the part which has been rebased).

No need to work on the SHA1 of the `copyBranch`: they will remain "archived" (referenced by the `copyBranch` HEAD) unchanged forever.
While your `currentBranch` will change as needed.

To restore the `copyBranch` will then be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Its much faster the `filter-branch` 10-720 times faster !!!

> The BFG will update your commits and all branches and tags so they are clean, but it doesn't physically delete the unwanted stuff.
>
> Examine the repo to make sure your history has been updated, and then use the standard git gc command to strip out the unwanted dirty data, which Git will now recognise as surplus to requirements.

You can use it to do whatever you wish and not just removing data.

---

#### How does The BFG do this faster than git-filter-branch?

> git-filter-branch steps through every commit in your history, executing whatever shell scripts you gave it against the contents- the full file tree -of each commit (so you can write a bash script to, for instance, delete a file), and this gives you a crazy amount of power. Too much power.
>
> Each commit you clean, only a small amount of data will have changed - but your bash script is running over the entire file tree of the commit. You're cleaning the same damn files over and over again. That is slow and, speaking broadly, totally freakin' redundant.
>
> Remember that for a given set of file contents, that file will only be stored once in the Git DB. Remember that a folder containing files & sub-folders will only be stored once, if the files & sub-folders have not changed. Why clean those precise files more than once? Git is begging you not to repeat yourself.
>
> This is the idea of The BFG: Clean a given Git object once. Remember the result: Store the 'dirty' id and the 'clean' id in a simple map, and every time you encounter an object (file or folder) while cleaning a commit, check its id to see if you've cleaned it before, and if you have, just use the cleaned object you stored from last time. Frequently, you get a big win and a massive sub-folder does not have to be cleaned, because you already have the Git-id of what it looks like when it's been purged.
>
> This kind of structure is also very amenable to parallelism, so while you have to clean commits in order, you can still actually fire off a ton parallel workers to clean their file contents, and get good use of all the CPU cores in your computer.

Comment: This is useful for removing files from history, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: If i understood him correctly he want to "walk" on all the commits with filter-branch and he is looking for something faster. correct me if im wrong,

Comment: Sure but he's using the same Tree-ish for all his new commits, only the commit hash is changing.  BFG is for when you need to change the Tree-ish and is unlikely to be much faster in his instance I would guess.

Comment: He asked to change the commit id, read the latest comments under the original post.

Comment: @andrew. can u please ping me at nir.geier@hpe.com, Thank you.

Comment: I'd already read his comments, my points are still the same.  BFG speeds up changing the tree SHAs.  His tree SHAs aren't changing.

Comment: I understood from him that he does wants to change the SHA-1

Answer (score 0):

If you're primarily interested in cleaning large files, you could also try  github's solution to large files: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: It has nothing to do with what he was asking.